# Using Set Interval Function to Animate

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

```
<html>
```

```
canvas {
    background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```
<script>
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


    var n = 5;
    const PI = 3.14;



    var randomWalk = function (n) {

        var list = [0, 1];
        var l = list.length;
        start = Math.round(n / 2);
        count = 0;

        while (start > 0 && start < n + 1) {

            rand = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * l)];
            if (rand == 1) { start = start + 1 }
            else { start = start - 1 };
            count = count + 1;

        };

        console.log(count);

    };

    var drawSquares = function (n) {
        for (i = 50; i <= n * 50; i = i + 50) {

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(i, 50, 50, 50);
            ctx.stroke();

        };

    };

    var drawDot = function (n) {
        x = ((50 * n) / 2) + 50;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, 75, 5, 0, 2 * PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();



    };


    var resetCanvas = function () {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };


    var moveDot = function (n) {
        drawSquares(n);
        drawDot(n);

        var list = [0, 1];
        var l = list.length;
        start = ((50 * n) / 2) + 50;
        count = 0;

        while (start > 50 && start < ((n * 50) + 50)) {



            rand = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * l)];
            if (rand == 1) { start = start + 50 }
            else { start = start - 50 };
            count = count + 1;
            //console.log(start);

            resetCanvas();
            drawSquares(n);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(start, 75, 5, 0, 2 * PI);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();

        };

        console.log(count);

    };



    //moveDot(n);

   setInterval(moveDot(n), 1500);

    </script>
```

The function below is the function that isn't working properly within the set interval function. This function takes the number of boxes as the input and based on a random choice of 0 or 1, it moves the dot to the left or to the right however it's not being shown.

I created the function titled moveDot to move the dot, however when placed in the set interval function the dot does not move. Any ideas as to why the function is not working properly would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `setInterval(moveDot(n), 1500);` - instead use `setInterval(moveDot, 1500, n);` because setInterval expects a function, not the result of calling a function

Comment: Or alternately `setInterval(() => moveDot(n), 1500);`